# Cant find or access my Local SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and went to connect to my LocalHost server; however, it can't be found. I then went to make sure the service was started, and it wasn't.  It wasn't even in the list where I could start it.

How can I start my local version of SQL Server 2008 if its not found in the services?

What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean "services" as in the Services control panel applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I start my local version of SQL Server 2008 if its not found in the services?

Surely that means that the install failed?  Try installing it again.
Are you sure you did not install the Management Tools instead?

Not sure if you used SQL Server 2000 before, but for 2008, it shows up as

```
SQL Server (<instance>)
```

<sub>Where  is MSSQLSERVER if it is the default instance.</sub>